# PHP MVC url Not Found 404

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am getting a **URL not found error in my MVC Php application**. The **.htacess** file seems fine and apache is configured well because the other application runs well. Am hosting my mysql db on amazon.

here is my code snippet.

**LoginForm.php**

/**
 * 
 */

```
 class LoginForm extends Controller {

public $model;

public function index() {

    //check if they are already logged in

    if (!isset($_SESSION['email'])) {


        require 'application/views/login/index.php';

    } else {
        //redirect to admin data
        header("Location:" . URL . "home");
    }
}

public function login() {
    // get the post

    $this->model = $this->loadModel('login');
    if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['country'])) {
        //  echo "priv_".$_POST["country"];
        $validate = $this->model->validate($_POST['email'], MD5($_POST['password']), $_POST["country"], 1);

        if ($validate != 0) {

            // get  all the data
            $data = $this->model->getByID($_POST['email']);

            /*
              echo "<pre>";
              var_dump($data);
              echo "</pre>";
              exit();

             */
            // set the session
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];


            /*
             * Privilege Sesssion settings Start
             * 
             */


            $_SESSION["pnya"] = $data[0]['pnya'];

            /*
             * Privilege Session End
             */
            header("Location:" . URL . "home");
        } else {
            header("Location:" . URL . "LoginForm");
        }
    } else {
        // @todo reload login page page
        header("Location:" . URL . "LoginForm");
        // @todo wth appropriate errors
    }
    // use php to check if its an email
    // if not set the errors
    // @todo use model to get dta a from staff and validate
    // @todo if it all succeeds then rdirect
}

public function logout() {
    // destroy the session
    session_start();
    session_destroy();

    // redirect to login page
    header("Location:" . URL . "LoginForm");
}
```

}

?>

.htacess

```
   Options -MultiViews
   RewriteEngine On
   Options -Indexes
   RewriteBase /MIS/ysw/

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

**config.php**

```
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);

  define('URL', 'http://42.11.223.45/MIS/ysw/');


  define('DB_TYPE', 'mysql');
  define('DB_HOST', 'XXX');
  define('DB_NAME', 'amazon');
  define('DB_USER', 'xxxx');
  define('DB_PASS', 'ddddd');
```

I have spent close to 13hrs trying to figure out what  I have not done right, but will be glad if informed

Comment: try `RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]` at last in .htaccess

Comment: @DhavalPurohit RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L] still doesn't work

Comment: then try `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [QSA,L]` and `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]`

Answer (score 0):

Please check if mod_rewrite is working, you can take help from here: https://docs.bolt.cm/3.0/howto/making-sure-htaccess-works